# IMacro won't click the submit button

Tags: firefox, submit, imacros

It appears to've selected the button (highlighted in blue, in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsIMM.png) but it doesn't submit/click it, it just stops there.

This is my code.

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !LOOP 1
SET !VAR1 0
SET !CLIPBOARD {{!EXTRACT}}
' open a webpage in the first tab 
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=file:///Users/mycomputer/Desktop/names.html
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:bodytxt&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
' open a new tab 
TAB OPEN
' get new tab to foreground 
TAB T=2 
' load another page 
URL GOTO=http://www.tumblr.com/ask_form/{{!EXTRACT}}.tumblr.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:ask_form ATTR=ID:question CONTENT=Hey!
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:ask_button
CLICK X=784 Y=166
```

Comment: I think I've found a solution. I added a slight delay before the last line of code.

    WAIT SECONDS=1

Answer (score 2):

Yea adding a

```
 WAIT SECONDS=1
```

could help ^_^

Although it's better to use:

```
 !WAITPAGECOMPLETE YES
```

In your script, this will make it wait until the page appears completely.

You can also slow down the speed of you imacro by using:!REPLAYSPEED

```
 SET !REPLAYSPEED SLOW
 STOPWATCH ID=home 

 SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
 STOPWATCH ID=home 

 SET !REPLAYSPEED MEDIUM
 STOPWATCH ID=home
```

Comment: It should be noted that !WAITPAGECOMPLETE is not compatible with FireFox or Chrome.

It is specific to IE. See: http://wiki.imacros.net/!WAITPAGECOMPLETE

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using Chrome, but this should work in Firefox, as well. I could make the macro wait for the submit button to appear, but it apparently went too fast to be able to actually click the button. I did an extraction first, just to wait for the appearance of the button. Then I cleared the extraction and made the *real* call to the submit button.

Here's a sample:

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:http://*/Blah.aspx?planid=*
' Wait for the appearance of a matching element
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 20
' iMacros clicks the button too fast, so pretend to extract text, first.
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=ID:*ButtonUpdate EXTRACT=TXT
' Clear the extraction
SET !EXTRACT NULL
' Click the Update button (fur realz)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=ID:*ButtonUpdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [web-developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) Once you have it install. go to In Miscellaneous > Display Ruler. Wherever you click/click+drag you get all the coordinates. Then use the CLICK command in imacros with the coordinates you got from web-developer.

I had to switch to firefox in order for the CLICK command to work. Since is not supported by Chrome browser. That did the trick on my end. Hope that helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ***DirectScreen Technology***. [Click here for details](http://wiki.imacros.net/DirectScreen_Technology).

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:ask_button
WAIT SECONDS=10
DS CMD=CLICK X={{!TAGX}} Y={{!TAGY}}
WAIT SECONDS=10
```

http://wiki.imacros.net/DirectScreen_Technology